# Regular Expression to Remove Subdomain from Root Domain in List - Notepad++ or Gvim

Tags: regex, vim, notepad++

I have a list of URLs stored in a .txt file (I'm using Windows 7).

The format of the URLs is this:

```
somesite1.com
somesite2.com
somesite3.com
sub1.somesite3.com
sub2.somesite3.com
sub3.somesite3.com
sub1.somesite3.net
sub1.somesite1.org
```

In notepad++, there is an option to use "find-replace with regular expressions", and I'm fairly sure that gvim allows the user of regular expressions (although I'm not entirely sure how to use them in Gvim).

Anyway, I don't know what to put in the find & replace boxes so it can go through the contents of the file and leave me with only the root domains.  If done properly, it would turn the above example list into this:

```
somesite1.com
somesite2.com
somesite3.com
somesite3.com
somesite3.com
somesite3.com
somesite3.net
somesite1.org
```

Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of ways of doing it for Vim (the trailing slashes are optional, too):

```
:%s/^.\+\.\ze[^.]\+\.[^.]\+$//
:%s/^.\+\.\([^.]\+\.[^.]\+\)$/\1/
```

See also `:help /\ze` etc. `\ze` and `\zs` are Vim-specific and very useful. There are also look-ahead and look-behind assertions which can be useful, in Vim and PCRE.

I believe Notepad++ uses PCRE; find `^.+\.([^.]+\.[^.]+)$` and replace it with `\1` should work (but I don't use Notepad++).

Be aware this won't work well with country code top level domains which use third-level registration - `example.com.au` would be turned into `com.au`. And then there are some countries which use second- *or* third-level registration under certain rules... if you care about those cases, you'll need more rules and a full parser would be neater than a regular expression (though as always it would be possible with regular expressions).

Answer (score 2):

Replace `^[^.]*\.(?=\w+\.\w+$)` with `<blank>`

Deciphered, this means:

- `^` = start of line
- `[^.]*` = any number of chars that are not a dot
- `\.` = a dot
- `(?=[^.]+\.[^.]+$)` = there must be exactly one word, one dot then one word from here to the end

**EDITED - Added look ahead for another dot**

**EDITED AGAIN - Changed look ahead for exactly one dot between words**

Comment: Eek!  `somesite1.com` -> `com`?  Time to rethink.

Comment: @Chris - nice pickup. thanks. I fixed it with the look-ahead (i think!)

Comment: There are a few quirks of look-ahead and look-behind assertions (especially with negative assertions&mdash;annoying things, those, considering how useful they should be) so I personally avoid them if at all possible through using real groups and/or `\zs`/`\ze` in Vim.

Comment: This will still turn `sub.sub.example.com` into `sub.example.com`, rather than `example.com` which is what's desired (though Robert gave no indication that he will run across fourth-level domains, it's a possibility and quite valid).

Comment: I want to use your code in mysql but I got this problem: "MySQL uses Henry Spencer's implementation of regular expressions, which is aimed at conformance with POSIX 1003.2" Any chance you can find solution without "?"

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman sure. I assume since MySQL doesn't support regex replace that your need is a little different and you want to *match*, but you haven't said exactly what. I'll take a guess it's "word.word.word", so try `\w+\.\w+.\w+`. If it's something else, let me know what.

Comment: May be I didn't understood the OP question, but in my case its: "a(1).a(2).a(3).a(4)...a(n-1).an" and I want to match "a(1).a(2).a(3).a(4)...a(n-2)." so I can replace it with empty string and get the true domain result: "a(n-1).a(n)". Tell me if you understand OP question differently, in such case I will ask a new one

Comment: @ilya are you able to use back references in your replacement?

Comment: I can't test in the moment, only on sunday. So far I only had problems with the question mark

Answer (score 0):

Replace whole of line to Last word and previous word of one.

```
%s/^.*\.\(\w\+\.\w\+\)$/\1/g
```

Note that vim require `\`,`(`,`)` for + like `\+`

UPDATE:

```
%s/^.*\.\([0-9a-z\-]\+\.[0-9a-z\-]\+\)$/\1/g
```

is better maybe.

Comment: `\w` won't cut it: `-` is valid in domain names.

Comment: i just tried to use this. and realized that there is a special case with some tlds in some countries, e.g .co.uk