# Java String truncate from URL address

Tags: java, string, split, substring

I have an URL address like: `http://myfile.com/File1/beauty.png`
I have to remove `http://site address/` from main string
That mean result should be `File1/beauty.png`

**Note:** site address might be anything(e.g some.com, some.org)

Comment: BUild Regex and extract the content you want. use sites like this to build the regex. http://txt2re.com/index-java.php3?s=http%3A%2F%2Fmyfile.org%2FFile1%2Fbeauty.png&submit=Show+Matches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, as you say, you only want to use the standard `String` methods then this should do it.

```
public static String getPath(String url){
        if(url.contains("://")){
            url = url.substring(url.indexOf("://")+3);
            url = url.substring(url.indexOf("/") + 1);
        } else {
            url = url.substring(url.indexOf("/")+1);
        }
        return url;
    }
```

If the url contains `://` then we know that the string you are looking for will come after the third `/`. Otherwise, it should come after the first. If we do the following;

```
System.out.println(getPath("http://myfile.com/File1/beauty.png"));
System.out.println(getPath("https://myfile.com/File1/beauty.png"));
System.out.println(getPath("www1.myfile.com/File1/beauty.png"));
System.out.println(getPath("myfile.co.uk/File1/beauty.png"));;
```

The output is;

```
File1/beauty.png
File1/beauty.png
File1/beauty.png
File1/beauty.png
```

Comment: I like your answer. Maybe you should extend getPath() to check, if it is prefixed by "://" and filter that out before extracting the string. This would be more failsafe - and you do not even need a loop to extract the string. Never the less - I'll give you my upvote :)

Comment: @INK - That's a good idea. I might test it with a series of URLs and see how that goes. If all works out I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Rudi Great :) You should consider removing the loop and replace it with: url = url.substring(url.indexOf("://")+3); (haven't tested it, but it should work). Just a performance thing though :)

Comment: @INK - That would retrieve the site domain as well, which I don't think they want.

Comment: Well, today is really not my day :D What about this one: url = url.substring(url.indexOf("://")+3); url = url.substring(url.indexOf("/") + 1); ? I just forgot the second line of code.

Comment: @SurendraJnawali - I removed the loop from the answer a little while ago. That address should work with the method both before and after the change. And it will work no matter how many addresses with "http://" you pass in.

Comment: @SurendraJnawali Now it's perfect. Why is it not the accepted answer anymore? :(

Answer (score 3):

See here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html

Just create a URL object out of your string and use URL.getPath() like this:

`String s = new URL("http://myfile.com/File1/beauty.png").getPath();`

If you don't need the slash at the beginning, you can remove it via `s.substring(1, s.length());`

Edit, according to comment:

If you are not allowed to use URL, this would be your best bet: [Extract main domain name from a given url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217271/extract-main-domain-name-from-a-given-url)

See the accepted answer. Basically you have to get a TLD list, find the domain and substract everything till the domain names' end.

Comment: I have to use only pure string methods substring or split see tags

Comment: Your answer is also useful: But Url exactly need url format( should have http://)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below approach to fetch the required data.

```
    String url = "http://myfile.org/File1/beauty.png";
    URL u = new URL(url);
    String[] arr = url.split(u.getAuthority());

    System.out.println(arr[1]);

    Output - /File1/beauty.png
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String s = "http://www.freegreatpicture.com/files/146/26189-abstract-color-background.jpg";
s = s.substring(s.indexOf("/", str.indexOf("/") + 1));
```

Comment: your result: /www.freegreatpicture.com/files/146/26189-abstract-color-background.jpg